# How to generate a helico-spiral by visualizing formula or equation

Tags: algorithm, math, formula, equation

[image]

I tried to visualize the formula of helico-spiral by programming but I failed to get the results I wanted. I don't know if I made an error when converting polar coordinates to Cartesian coordinates.

Here is my code:

```
float alpha;
float beta;
float A;

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    float theta = i * 0.1 * $PI;
    float r = A * exp(1.0 / tan(alpha) * theta);

    float x = r * sin(beta) * cos(theta);
    float y = r * sin(beta) * sin(theta);
    float z = -1.0 * A * cos(beta);
    
    vector pos = set(x, z, 0); // point position
}
```

[image]

I customized `alpha`, `beta` and `theta` and wanted to find the point coordinates on the helix through the radius `r`.

Answer (score 0):

Start with parametrized spiral:

```
H = max height
R = max radius
n = number of screws
t = <0,1> input parameter

a = 2.0*M_PI*n*t;
r = R*t;
h = H*(1.0-t);

x = r*cos(a);
y = r*sin(a);
z = h;
```

Now just as you want to parametrize the spiral by `r` just compute `t` form `r`:

```
t = r/R;
```

so:

```
t = r/R;
h = H*(1.0-t);
a = 2.0*M_PI*n*t;
x = r*cos(a);
y = r*sin(a);
z = h;
```

so simply do a for loop where `r` goes from `0` to `R` with some small step and render lines between the computed points ...

Also the dependence between `H,R` is:

```
tan(Beta) = R/H
---------------
R = H*tan(Beta)
H = R/tan(Beta)
Beta = atan(R/H)
```